# Facing issue while getting access token from Auth0 Management API using C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I was trying to get the Auth0 Management API access token using HttpClient request but getting Forbidden 403 error. I have also tried to call the api using Auth0 management api sdk for C# and Rest API still getting error.
Can anyone guide me how to get the access token from Auth0 for Management API?

**Below code I tried using HttpClient**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://{your domain}/");
var response = await client.PostAsync("oauth/token", 
new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
{ "grant_type", "clent_credentials" },
{ "client_id", "{client_Id}" },
{ "client_secret", "{client_secret}" },
{ "audience", "https://{your domain}/api/v2/" }
}));
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(content);
}
```

Response :
StatusCode : 403
ReasonParse : 'Forbidden'

**I have also tried the authorize call using rest client as below**

```
RestClient client1 = new RestClient("https://{your domain}/authorize");
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.Post;
request.AddParameter(
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"grant_type=clent_credentials&client_id={client_Id}&
client_secret={client_secret}&
audience=https://{your domain}/api/v2/", ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response1 = await client1.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Response :
StatusCode : not found
Content-type : text/plain
content-length : 10

**I want to get the access token from Auth0 to access Management API.**

Comment: If you are calling this endpoint: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-token you're missing the "code" parameter which you should have obtained from an earlier call to authorize. That explains why your first call returns a 403. That is not something we can fix for you.

Comment: You should try with Get request instead of Post request when you login accroding to  this doc:https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#social

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in your request parameter "{ "grant_type", "**clent_credentials**" }"
"i" is missing in the client ,It should be { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },

Comment: typo questions should be flagged as such. [/help/privileges/flag-posts](/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34583412)